# Вывод контента с разных страниц на PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, имеется данный код на PHP, который парсит контент с одной страницы. А как вывести например, контент с разных страниц. Например, хочу вывести также столбиком данные о концертах и билетах,только с описанием, но дело в том, что описание концерта находится уже в самом билете(то есть мы видим описание билета, только при клике туда)

```
<?php
    // с кодировкой возможны проблемы, поэтому если вдруг появятся каркозябры, попробуйте добавить следующую строчку кода 


    // сторонняя страница сайта, с которой будем брать контент. 
    $content = file_get_contents('https://philharmonic.by/ru');

    // определяем начало необходимого фрагмента кода, до которого мы удалим весь контент
    $pos = strpos($content, '<div class="row">');

    // удаляем все до нужного фрагмента
    $content = substr($content, $pos);

    // находим конец необходимого фрагмента кода
    $pos = strpos($content, '</div>');

    // отрезаем нужное количество символов от конца фрагмента
    $content = substr($content, 0, $pos);

    //если в нужном контенте встречается не нужный кусок текста, то его вырезаем
    $content = str_replace('текст, который нужно вырезать','', $content); 

    // выводим необходимый контент
    echo $content;
?>
```

Разобрался как сделать, чтобы с одной страницы  выводились разные данные, но как сделать так, чтобы выводились эти же данные, плюс описание, но с внутренней страницы

- [страница с билетами](https://philharmonic.by/ru)
- [страница с описанием](https://philharmonic.by/ru/concert/abonement-no-2-debyut-yunyh-talantov-20)

ПЫТАЛСЯ ВЫТАЩИТЬ КОД ПО АЙДИШНИКУ И КЛАССУ,НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ.НЕ ПОДСКАЖЕТЕ КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ?ЦИКЛ FOREACH НЕ ПОДХОДИТ

Answer (score 1):

Нужно искать более уникальные части html кода как метки конца и начала нужного фрагмента. Открываем исходный текст страницы <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> и ищем <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> чтобы ваши метки находились только раз.

Если не получиться то нужно использовать более сложные инструменты [типа](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php) или [лучше](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) и искать нужный элемент по условиям типа:

```
$article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
```